# Скачивание файла в JS

Tags: javascript, файлы, get, fetch, download

появилась необходимость в скачивание файла, который мне отдаёт сервер.
Вот мой запрос:

```
const downloadFile = async (url) => {
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: token,
                    },
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Something wrong");
                }
            };
```

```
downloadFile(`http://localhost:8080/papers/download/abstractFile/${paperId}`);
```

Но скачивание не происходит, хотя в Postman всё работает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать данный функционал и что я делаю не так.

Comment: А что в response? Просто тут может быть трабла с серверной частью, где идет некорректная отдача заголовков?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper в response мне ничего не возвращается, но статус запроса 200 и вроде как никаких ошибок нету

Comment: Ну а как тогда построена серверная часть отдачи файла?